# Positivity of Some Polynomials over the Positive Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$p(t)=\sum_{k=l+1}^{r} c_k t^k -\sum_{k=0}^{l} c_k t^k$$ where $r$ is a natural number, $0\leq l \leq r-1$ and $c_k \geq 0$.

Suppose $p(1)=0$.
Is it always the case that $p(t)>0$ for all $t>1$?

Comment: Hi @Joseph Frank Gordon, welcome to MSE. Could you please provide some working on the question? Thank you!

Comment: I have added a few dollar signs to your post, making the math actually render. Also, consider giving your post a more descriptive title. Finally. please add [some context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) to your question post (where it's from, what you have tried, where you're stuck and so on). At the moment it is a pure problem statement, and we prefer not to have such opsts here.

Comment: Is there anything given about $r$? For $r=0$, the choice of $l$ is impossible. So $r\ge 1$ is arbitrary? Can you write down an example yourself? Let $r=5$, $l=3$ and choose values for $c_0,c_1,\ldots c_5$.

Comment: r is a natural number

Comment: So have you computed $p(t)$ for this example?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do but got stuck

Comment: I guess you meant $p(1)=0.$

Comment: Sure sure, it's p(1)=0. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $p(1)=0.$ For $t>1$ we have $$\displaylines{\sum_{k=l+1}^rc_kt^k\ge \left (\sum_{k=l+1}^rc_k\right )t^{l+1}\\ =\left (\sum_{k=0}^lc_k\right )t^{l+1}>\sum_{k=0}^l c_kt^k}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. But the index of the last sum should be freom $k=0$ to $k=l$.

Comment: @Arthur. That’s because $p(1)=0$.